# Is there any step available for integration of Amazon-chime-sdk-js in angular8?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, angular8

Is there any step available to integrate Amazon-chime-sdk-js in angular 8 and Node js?
I am beginner in Amazon-chime services. and I want to create a video conference meeting in Angular-8/Node js using Amazon-chime-sdk-js.

Thank you all.